# Android Asyn loading ImageView in ListVIew, image changed auto and not correct

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I have a ListView to show a photo gallery with short title(ImageView + TexiView). I used AsyncTask to do the download duty. But the problem is sometimes it will show wrong image then changed suddenly(may happen many times).
For example: IA B C will show in ListView, image m1 m2 m3 for ABC respectively.
when I run the application, the imageView for A may display m1,m2 or m3 and change frequently. 
Here is my code:

**DownClass:**

```
  public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage = null;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result == null){
            bmImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
          }else{
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
    }
}
```

**Adapter for ListView:**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    item item1 = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    TextView ttv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.p_title);
    TextView itv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.p_price);
    /**
    *Download Image
    */
    String img_url;
    img_url = item1.getImg_url();
    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img))
            .execute(img_url);

    ttv.setText(item1.getTitle());
    itv.setText("$"+item1.getPrice());
    return convertView;
}
```

**Activity:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_promotion2);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    getPromotionByRequest(previousPage, data);//Get Data for items

    itemAdapter = new promotionAdapter(this, items);
    //progress..........
    gridView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    setupListViewListener();
}
```

Comment: Show all the parts that you use. What happens after async returns, how you populate the adapter, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, unfortunately problem still happen.
Finally, I did solved it by use **"Picasso"** in each adapter, such powerful

Answer (score 0):

try with viewholder instesd of getview

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_item_recyclerView, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

orelse
try with this in getview also
create layoutinflator:

```
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and create another view reference:
then inflate the child views:

```
View v = convertView;
v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_namehere, parent, false);
TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: viewholder sounds good, but I don't how to use it properly. Can you write a whole sample adapter for me, I will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
item item1 = getItem(position);
ViewHolder vh = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
    vh.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    vh.ttv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.p_title);
    vh.itv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.p_price);
    convertView.setTag(vh);
}else{
    vh = (ViewHoldler)convertView.getTag();
}

/**
*Download Image
*/
String img_url;
img_url = item1.getImg_url();
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img))
        .execute(img_url);

ttv.setText(item1.getTitle());
itv.setText("$"+item1.getPrice());
return convertView;
```

}

```
public class ViewHolder {
  public ImageView iv;
  public TextView ttv;
  public TextView itv;
}
```

Maybe it is not correct，you can try...I've been a long time without a listview

Answer (score 0):

create view holder class in getview() method like bellow.

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
```

and later add view to holder like bellow code

```
holder.imageviewname= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_image);
holder.textviewname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_text);
```

for more info refer doc https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: I have change to Volley->ImageLoder and used ViewHolder as you said. But still ....